# Outgoing TCP port matches listening port

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, lsof

I've encountered a weird happenstance where the results of my

```
lsof | grep 40006
```

produced

```
java      29722     appsrv   54u     IPv6           71135755        0t0      TCP localhost:40006->localhost:40006 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Generally I see

```
java      30916     appsrv   57u     IPv6           71143812        0t0      TCP localhost:43017->localhost:40006 (ESTABLISHED)
```

where the ports do not match on either side of the arrow. While lsof was producing the former result, I could not start an application which attempts to listen on the port 40006 even though the socket is configured as SO_REUSEADDR.

Can this happen? Should it?

uname gives: Linux femputer 2.6.32-24-server #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 06:21:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Note: for the first lsof result, the application listening on 40006 was terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to arrange such a connection by creating a socket, binding it to `127.0.0.1:40006`, then `connect()` it to `127.0.0.1:40006`.  (Note: no `listen()`).  I believe this is called an "active-active open".

The following program demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in sa = {
        .sin_family = PF_INET,
        .sin_port = htons(40006),
        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK) };

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (s < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        return 1;
    }

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        return 1;
    }

    pause();

    return 0;
}
```

The reason that the port cannot be re-used is because the port is not listening - it is an outgoing port.

Comment: I've omitted something from the second lsof output that I now regret. The fist lsof result was the complete print-out. The second in it's entirety is

Comment: java      30916     appsrv   57u     IPv6           71143812        0t0      TCP localhost:43017->localhost:40006 (ESTABLISHED)
\n myapp 30957     appsrv    4u     IPv4           71143810        0t0      TCP *:40006 (LISTEN)
\n myapp 30957     appsrv    5u     IPv4           71143811        0t0      TCP localhost:40006->localhost:43017 (ESTABLISHED)

For the case of the first lsof result, myapp was terminated at the time and the line presented persisted after I found I could not restart it. Perhaps myapp did not shut down cleanly? I will check the shutdown code.

Comment: I'm assuming the left side of the localhost:43017->localhost:40006 part is random, I don't know what to search for to find out what factors into it. I thought there would be mechanisms to prevent the overlapping, but I have no idea what they are if they are not enabled by default.

Comment: @user535674: It could also be that the *client* application (the one that usually does the `connect()`) is inadvertently creating the loop, if the server isn't running when it tries to connect.  At any rate, *some* application is still running and holding that connection open (PID 29722 in your example).  (There *are* mechanisms to stop this - it only happens if your application specifically does a `bind()` before `connect()` as in my sample C code.  I suspect your client application is wrongly using `bind()`).

Comment: The client application uses the java Socket constructor, new java.net.Socket(host, port), where host is a String and port is an int. According to the JVM source code, that call will bind to local port 0, which should choose a free port number. I guess this time it didn't.

Comment: @user535674: Well, if this happens infrequently, I suppose it's possible that the port 40006 was the one chosen because it *was* free, since the server wasn't running.  If you want to avoid this happening, you can make sure the server uses a port outside of the local port range (by default, a port lower than 32768).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the two `40006` ports were on different interfaces?

Comment: There is only one interface on the computer.

Comment: Unless a distinction is made between lo and eth0, since both applications are on the same computer and connect via the host name localhost.